# App / Plugin to flip between active screens

Tags: browser-addons, plugins, screensaver, browser-plugin

Bit of an odd request, but I'm coming up with nothing after spending a solid hour searching Google.

I am looking for either a browser plugin or separate application that will periodically change the active window/application/browser tab. The purpose of this is for a wallboard display. We want to setup several dashboards / browser windows, and have it periodically (based on a defined timer) change between these active windows.

As an example, we might have 4 separate webapges (can be tabs or separate browser instanced) that we wish to display (network monitor, ticketing system, world clocks and live webcam). We would like the screen to change between these in order, leaving each up on the screen for a few minutes at a time.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it.  [Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/) is an excellent utility for manipulating Windows (I am assuming Windows OS).

First start a new instance of firefox for each window you want open.  Consider using the [fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/FF_Fullscreen/?src=search) extension to start firefox fullscreen, and without any toolbars.

Then use the task scheduler to switch between each window periodically.  The nircmd to do this is:

```
nircmd win activate ititle "the title name of the firefox window you want to bring to the front"
```

The `activate` command brings the titled window to the front, over the other windows.  The `ititle` parameter looks for the string in the title of the window.  You can find the title by hovering over the firefox window in the taskbar.  You can use part of the title if it changes with each refresh.

You would have four scheduled tasks, each bringing each of the firefox instances you want to the front, and separated by a minute or however long you want each one displayed.

Comment: [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) is another good choice for this. You could do all the logic in a single script, or you could split it up, and call the script from another utility (e.g. Task Scheduler).

Comment: Google Chrome, not Firefox, has a `--kiosk` switch.